# Admin not working on development site

Tags: admin, .htaccess

A client's web hosting support have created a development site for me @ `dev.example.com`.

When I try to load `http://dev.example.com/admin`, I am redirected to `https://dev.example.com/index.php/admin/`, and receive the error:

> The requested URL /index.php/admin/ was not found on this server.

`mod_rewrite` is enabled, and the `.htaccess file` is the same as the production site @ `example.com`.

`web/unsecure/base_url` & `web/secure/base_url` are set okay in the `core_config_data` database table.

How do I fix this please? Thanks.

Comment: Did you change admin url??

Comment: @Kothari: thanks for your assistance. I didn't change it myself. Where would I check to see if it has been changed?

Comment: check app->etc->local.xml. Share your url

Comment: There is no file there, only a pointer, which points to another local.xml elsewhere I believe, which contains: 
`<admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <frontName><![CDATA[admin]]></frontName>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>`

Comment: Ok share your url

Comment: I'd rather not, as I have some patches to install. :-)

Comment: How do I turn off https in the admin URL?

Comment: Goto phpmyadmin and then table name core_config_data change web/unsecure/base_url https://domain.com into http://domain.com and also change web/secure/base_url https://domain.com into http://domain.com

Comment: change https:// into http://

Comment: Done. Still loads on https://, even after clearing cache.

Comment: goto your phpmyadmin and search https://domain.com. then it will show where and all you configure.

Comment: There are only 5 entries, and none of them are https://

Comment: to delete var->cache and var-> session folder

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32159/discussion-between-steve-and-kothari).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Web hosting support told me:

the /admin site was automatically forwarding to HTTPS. This must have been set in the app itself, as there was no such setting in the web server, the .htaccess files or the core_config_data table. When forwarding to HTTPS, though, it was referencing the wrong Document Root and therefore not finding the correct path.